# How to access objective-c properties in class methods

Tags: objective-c, singleton

It's impossible to access an objective-c property in a class method like this:

```
@interface MyClass
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray myStudents;
@end

@implementation MyClass
+ (id)myClassMethod { return self.myStudents; } // bad
@end
```

This MyClass happens to be a singleton object, so is there a way I can be able to access that object using a class method in MyClass? Like UIApplication does with `[UIApplication sharedApplication]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your trying to implement a singleton method then you should be returning an instance of *MyClass*, not an NSMutableArray of whatever data. Something like this:

```
static MyClass * singleton ;

@interface MyClass : NSObject {}

@implementation MyClass

static NSString * LOCK = @"Whatever";

+ (MyClass *) sharedInstance {
    @synchronized(LOCK) {
        if(singleton == nil) {
            singleton = [[MyClass alloc] init];
        }
    }

    return singleton;
}

@end
```

This is pseudo-code, but you get the gist. Then you use it somewhere else like so:

```
MyClass * foobar = [MyClass sharedInstance];
[foobar doSomeStuff];
```

Comment: OK - I thought it would be something like that. I thought that `MyClass * singleton` would have to be a property, because that's how it works in Java

Comment: You *can* store it as an ivar, but I would never make it a property since that effectively adds instance level methods to the class, which is not what you want for a singleton.

Answer (score 2):

Actually singleton object is an ordinary object that has only one instance which is returned via a class method in ObjC or via static method in C++. It means that you need one class method like this:

```
+(MyClass*) shared {
    static MyClass* shared_class = NULL;

    @synchronized( shared_class ) {
        if( !shared_class ) {
           shared_class = [MyClass new];
        }
    }

    return shared_class;
}
```

Comment: Upvoting for placing the singleton variable in the correct place.